# Error: 'User' object has no attribute 'get' in django-tables

Tags: django

My aim is to print data from database as a table. Can i do it with simple forms?

**views.py**

```
from django.views.generic.detail import DetailView
from django.views.generic.list import ListView    
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import *

class IndexView(ListView):
    template_name = 'Dashboard/index.html'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return ccc

class CourseView(DetailView):
    model = Course
    template_name = 'Dashboard/course.html'

class TeacherView():
    def teacher(request):
        return render(request, 'Dashboard/teacher.html', {'table' : User.objects.all()})
```

**teacher.html**

```
{% load render_table from django_tables2 %}
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>All Teachers</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        {% render_table table %}
    </body>
</html>
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views
app_name = 'Dashboard'
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.IndexView.as_view(), name='index'),
    path('<int:pk>/', views.CourseView.as_view(), name='detail'),
    path('teacher/', views.User, name='teacher'),
]
```

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models

class User(models.Model):
    unam = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    uid = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    umob = models.IntegerField()
    umail = models.EmailField()
    uimg = models.CharField(max_length=1000, default='null')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.unam
```

**settings.py**

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django_tables2',
    'Dashboard.apps.DashboardConfig',
```

My aim is to print data from database as a table. Can i do it with simple forms?

Answer (score 0):

You do not have a "User" view inside your views.py.

```
path('teacher/', views.User, name='teacher')
```

But a TeacherView. I suggest you use a Template View and define your Users Context
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/class-based-views/base/#templateview

And if I might suggest, do not prefix Model Attributes with "u". You User Model already speaks for itself. Even though naming it "User" might clash at a certain point of time with the Auth User Model from Django.

And last but not least try to avoid * imports if you can

Comment: Now it says:TypeError at /Dashboard/teacher/
object() takes no parameters

Answer (score 0):

change the views.py as follows

```
from django.views import View
class TeacherView(View):
   def get(self, request):
     return render(request, 'Dashboard/teacher.html', {'table' : User.objects.all()})
```

Now also change the urlpatterns as follows

`path('teacher/', views.TeacherView.as_view(), name='teacher')`

I hope this works for you.